# Kafka Steams Windowing on a different value

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When you create a window using kafka streams I assume it uses the timestamp the record was published?  Is there anyway to window by something else.

My use case is our record value object contains a timestamp and that is what we want to window on.

If I do something like this it will window on published time stamp.  I want to window by myObject.getCallTimestamp()

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, MyObject> windowedPageViewCounts = pageViews
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), myObjectSerde))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)))
    .count();
```

EDIT:

Based on recommendation below I believe this is what I need to be doing?

```
public class RecordTimeStampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {

    //default timestamp extractor
    private FailOnInvalidTimestamp failOnInvalidTimestamp = new FailOnInvalidTimestamp();

    @Override
    public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord, long l) {
        //could also use consumerRecord.topic().equals("mytopic")
        if(consumerRecord.value() instanceof MyClass) {
            MyClass myClass = (MyClass) consumerRecord.value();
            return myClass.getRecordTimestamp().toEpochMilli();
        }
        return failOnInvalidTimestamp.extract(consumerRecord,l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement and configure (via `default.timestamp.extractor`) a custom `TimestampExtractor` that returns `myObject.getCallTimestamp()`.

See the docs for details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#streams-developer-guide-timestamp-extractor